# how to refresh apache kylin cubes?

Tags: hadoop, kylin

I am able to create kylin cubes and build kylin cubes successfully.Hive is getting incremental data with time intervals.But my kylin cube is not getting that incremental data at regular intervals.we tried kylin refreshment settings using fact table partition column,start and end date specifications.I got totally two problems,

1. If i am using refreshment settings,then fact table is not showing any data while select that fact table.
2. If I am not using that settings then my cube is not getting incremental data from hive tables.

which one i have to follow for getting fresh data into kylin cube.Everytime i have use cube build  for getting fresh data from hive?is there any alternative for automatic refreshment ?

Comment: which dates we have to give in start date and end date specifications?

Comment: anybody have any idea please share me ways for  refreshing kylin cube automatically.